# Smart Card Authentication using JMETER

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am doing end to end performance testing of `REST API` using `JMETER`. The first step of any End to *End Performance Testing is Authentication*. My project supports only Smart Card Authentication, `PKI` Card. It does not have a facility to log in using *Email Id* and *Password*. If I open user interface, it asks me to enter Smart Card, then it navigates me to *Organizations Entitlement Service* and gets authenticated.

```
Go to JMETER -> Set HTTP Authorization. It does not work
```

Is there a way in `JMETER` to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need Client Certificate authentication.

In this case you need to use the following component:

- [CSV Data Set](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) that will contains the alias in the keystore
- [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) that will read the keystore certificate and use the current alias extracted by CSV Data Set to find the certificate
- Create a Keystore using client certificates and keytool utility

  > keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore ./loadtest.jks -deststoretype JKS -srcstorepass password -deststorepass password
- Reference it using :

  - -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore
  - -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password_of_keystore